# Coexistence among global operator<< and member operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Does anyone know how to make these two overloaded operators coexist?

```
#include<iostream> 

template< typename T > 
class A; 

template< typename T > 
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const A<T>& e ); 

template< typename T > 
class A 
{ 
   A& operator <<( const A& e ); 
   friend std::ostream& operator<< <>( std::ostream& o, const A<T>& e ); 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
   // program
   return 0; 
} 

// def A<T>::A& A::operator <<( const A& e ); 
// def std::ostream& operator<< <>( std::ostream& o, const A<T>& e );
```

error:

```
$ g++ prov.cpp -o prov
prov.cpp:13:33: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
prov.cpp:13:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
prov.cpp:13:36: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

I’m sorry for my bad English. For this reason I write little.

Greeting and thanks!

Comment: Are you running into an error?

Comment: g++ version 4.7.3 
compiler throws this error:
prov.cpp:13:33: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
prov.cpp:13:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
prov.cpp:13:36: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and I found that adding ```using namespace std;``` then the compiler will not throw the errors. But I still didn't find out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>( ... );
```

in the friend declaration.  (I'm not sure: my policy has always
been to define the friend `inline`, so it didn't matter if it
was a template or not.  But this looks like the examples in the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround solution:

```
template< typename T > 
class A 
{ 
   A& operator <<( const A& e ); 
   template< typename T1 > 
   friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& o, const A<T1>& e ); 
};
```

Here the renaming of `typename T` is necessary, or you will re-declare the template parameter inside the scope of class A and the compiler will complain.